# What is the root directory that H2O Flow UI exports to?

Tags: hadoop, h2o

For example, I want to export a model (not the POJO) from an `h2o flow` running on a remote hadoop cluster, so that I can upload it to my local machine h2o session and and view the output metrics without having to train the model again with the same data. However, when I try to export the model from `flow` (under some name "export_test"), I cannot find it. To start the h2o session, I am doing:

```
$cd cd h2o-3.14.0.6-mapr5.2
$hadoop jar h2odriver.jar -nodes 5 -mapperXmx 6g -output hdfsOutputDirName
```

but I don't see any file called "export_test" in the hdfsOutputDirName nor in the *h2o-3.14.0.6-mapr5.2* directory (which is where models are stored whenever I export them when using `flow` on my local machine) so I'm not sure where it could be going. Is there a default base directory that h2o flow may be exporting to somewhere on the node I am remoted into (like baseDir/export_test)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model will be saved relative to where the particular node you are talking to is running.  So, on the local filesystem on the host where the YARN container that the REST API client (like R, Python, or H2O Flow) is talking to is placed.

This is probably not where you want the model to be saved.

You can explicitly specify an "hdfs://" path to save the model to, and then find it in hdfs.

[ That "-output hdfsOutputDirName" is actually an artifact of inheriting from org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner, and isn't used for anything. ]

Comment: When I run `flow` on my local machine, exporting models and .hex files results in those things being downloaded into the directory I launched the h2o.jar file from. But the same does not happen when running `flow` from the hadoop node I am remoting into. From you answer, it seems like it should be downloaded to *h2o-3.14.0.6-mapr5.2* on the node I am ssh-ed into (I'm not very familiar with hadoop terms, as I only want to use it for running `flow` in my case), but I am not seeing this.

Comment: If you use an hdfs path (which is recommended) then the model will be saved to hdfs and can be retrieved from anywhere that can see hdfs.  If you don't use an hdfs path, then the path is local to the host where Flow is connected to (the IP address in your browser).  You may or may not be able to login to that host.  This is probably not the same host where you ssh'd to start h2o.

Comment: Adding note to self and others that may also be in similar situation as I was when posted this question (ie. no experience with `h2o` or `hadoop`): Access to the hdfs would be done with something like `$hadoop fs <command to retrive files>` or by mounting a nsf gateway for hadoop on local file system.